# getting Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses error in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

trying to run a new project but getting this error

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses

i have tried adding the reflect dependency but not working
I also have added the dependencies but still not able to resolve the problem

my app level build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sdd.calender"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
  }
}
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.4.0'
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")

}
```

project level build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"    
  }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? If so, what was the solution

Answer (score 0):

You added the reflect dependency to your project-level gradle file, not the app-level file. Try moving the `implementation` line to that file instead.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: @SagarDeshmukh Just to clarify: do not use the `classpath` function in the app file. Instead, did you add `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")` inside the the app's `dependencies` block?

Comment: yes i have did that but still getting the error

Comment: i have updated the code you can see it

Answer (score 0):

Replace from `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10")` to `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version")`

And from `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"` to `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: This is not working.